# mininet host. IP() cannot follow the change of IP address after running DHCP

Tags: mininet

I created a mininet networknetwork and connect it  to a pox controller. In each host,  DHCP is run and IP is reallocated by the DHCP server in POX. When I ran host.cmd('ifconfig') in my source code , the printed IP address is  the new IP allocated by DHCP, but host. IP() is still the old IP. How can I update host. IP?

Comment: please share the source code and clarify wheather the command host.IP() is executed on mininet command line

Comment: I defined my command in net. py and cli. py.  the code is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `host.defaultIntf().updateIP()`

From [documentation](https://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1link_1_1Intf.html#af81cf32e2a523be6266eb21be8c60d49):

> Return updated IP address based on ifconfig.

Source: https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2014-January/003822.html